Serre duality for arbitrary sheaves?
Let $X$ be a connected proper Cohen-Macaulay scheme over a field $k$ of dimension $n$. Is there an example of an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ such that Serre duality
$$
\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}_X}^{n-i}(\mathcal{F},\omega_X) \cong H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F})^\lor
$$
does not hold?

How arbitrary is arbitrary? $\mathcal{F}$ is quasicoherent or?

A priori, I don't want to make any assumptions on $\mathcal{F}$. If there is an example where $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent, I'd be even more interested.

Well you probably want to assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module otherwise the Ext group on the left doesn't really make sense.

I edited the question accordingly. Thanks!
